# Cannot convert lambda expression VB .net to C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert some VB code to C#. The below VB.Net code is working.

GroupCategories is a List of grouped categories, which is simply getting some data and storing it in a list.

```
For Each Groups In From g In GroupCategories Group By GroupInfo = New With {g.Id, g.Name} Into SubCategories = Group Select GroupInfo, SubCategories
        For Each sc In Groups.SubCategories
            ....
        Next

        If Groups.GroupInfo.Id Is Nothing Then
        ....
        End If
    End If
Next
```

My attempt to convert in C#:

```
foreach (var Groups in from g in GroupCategories group GroupInfo by new {g.Id, g.Name } into SubCategories select new { GroupInfo, SubCategories })
{
    ....
}
```

I have tried a few online coverters but dont convert successfully. Ive read MSDN for its C# equivalent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx but i still cant seem to get this working.

The current error is

***Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type***

Reading on the error gives me some recommendations but i'm still getting errors converting. Im not sure what else i can try as i have tried a combination of splitting the for each group into its own section but similar errors pop up. Can anyone see where im going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following linq query:

```
from g in GroupCategories
    group g by new { g.Id, g.Name } into SubCategories 
select new { SubCategories.Key, SubCategories }
```

Or the equivalent:

```
GroupCategorias.GroupBy(g => new { g.Id, g.Name })
               .Select(group => new { group.Key, group });
```

Quite frankly, in embedded queries I prefer the latter syntax.

Comment: Thanks - i tried the code listed first which resolved the error partially (albeit not been able to test it fully yet). I couldnt see where you would have created GroupInfo (which is in the Select clause)? I've amended the original post to include an If statement which i left out just to keep the code short but later in the code its used

Comment: @Computer `GroupInfo` in the c# version is an anonymous type. There isn't really that much use in naming the type to begin with as it will always be recoverable through the `Key` property of the created groups. I'm not even sure if the c# syntax allows naming the anonymous type you are grouping by (I don't recall ever doing it) and I can't test it at the moment.

Comment: Isn't the select `.Select(group => new { group.Key, group });` redundant?

Comment: @Magnus Yes, it probably is, but I'm not sure what the context is so I've just made the query as similar as possible to the OP's.

Comment: @Magnus - i wasnt aware of that. I use .Select quite often (or are you referring to the new type created)?

Comment: @Comptuer The whole select clause.`GroupBy` or `group` already returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T>>` and `IGrouping` is an `IEnumerable<T>` with an added property `Key` that represents the key you are grouping by.